# How to add editors or viewers for multiple spreadsheets from a range?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i have a spreadsheet, and there are available spreadsheet IDs and emails in range.
Is it possible to add an editor or viewer for a specific spreadsheet from a range list? As mentioned in the worksheet, some optional functionality is also required.

[Worksheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YVnRuLed_FvO0fRMWms4GLNPdal3LmWpqUJNg5r_r-U/edit#gid=0)

I am building or looking for a standalone script.

```
function addTrigger(){
  var sID = 1YVnRuLed_FvO0fRMWms4GLNPdal3LmWpqUJNg5r_r-U;
  var sheet = sID.getActiveSheet()
 //Rest codes will be here.
});
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Although I saw your provided Spreadsheet from `As mentioned in the worksheet, some optional functionality is also required.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sure, plz look at the Col C & D, there is checkbox that permit allow, disallow, add, remove.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted and the discussion has also already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing both answer and discussion.

Comment: You can also participate:) Because it's still `awaiting the standalone compatible script`, but his is working with an errors.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

You can try this script for your desired output. I am using Installable onEdit trigger on a bounded script.

### Installable trigger:

[image]

### Code:

```
function addViewersAndEditors() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = dataRange.filter((_, i) => i == sheet.getActiveRange().getRow() - 1).flat(); //extracting the data from spreadsheet
  var sheetID = data[0] //sheet Id
  var userEmail = data[1] // user Email
  var viewer = data[2]; // Add/Remove viewer
  var editor = data[3]; // Add/Remove editor

// Function that checks if Column C and Column D is true, if so adds as editor 
  if (editor === true) {
    editorAccess(sheetID, userEmail, editor)
  } else {
    editorAccess(sheetID, userEmail, editor)
  }
// Function that checks if Column C is true, if so adds as viewer
  if (viewer === true) {
    viewerAccess(sheetID, userEmail, viewer)
  } else {
    viewerAccess(sheetID, userEmail, viewer)
  }

}
// Function that adds a user as viewer if the Column C is tick
function viewerAccess(sheetID, userEmail, boolean) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID)
  if (boolean === true) {
    ss.addViewer(userEmail)
  }
  else {
    ss.removeViewer(userEmail);
  }
}
// Function that adds a user as editor if the Column D is tick
function editorAccess(sheetID, userEmail, boolean) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID)
  if (boolean === true) {
    ss.addEditor(userEmail)
  }
  else {
    ss.removeEditor(userEmail);
  }
}
```

### Output:

### [image]
References:

[Class SpreadSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

[AddViewer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addvieweruser)

[AddEditor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addeditoremailaddress)

[RemoveViewer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removevieweremailaddress)

[RemoveEditor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeeditoremailaddress)

[Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Does it worked from your end? I am rececing 'Exception: Invalid argument: id' on standalone.

Comment: Yes it does work on my end. I have not tried it yet on standalone but can you run the script again while selecting any cell in column C as an active cell

Comment: When running the script are you using a sheet with the same format you have provided? Also can you try to rerun the script while selecting any cell in the row data? (In your given sample sheet row 2 and row 3)

Comment: This coming a `lots of errors` in Executions